# How do I call functions from other files?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have three functions and they're stored in 3 separate files. I'm going to make up some examples and the calculations may not make sense, but it's to give you a general idea of how I'm using the functions and its values.

function_1.py

```
import numpy as np

def function_1(A, B, C):

    E = A + B
    D = A*B-C
    return D
```

function_2.py

```
import numpy as np

def function_2(D, E):

    F = D/E
    return F
```

This is the function I'm trying to work on at the moment:

function_3.py

```
import numpy as np
import function_1 as f1
import function_2 as f2

def function_3(A, B, G, H):

    D = f1.function_1(A, B, C)
    E = f1.function_1(A, B, C)

    for k in range(G):
        array[k] = f2.function_2(D, E) # it should be G/H
    return array
```

Basically, function_2 uses values returned by function_1 to do calculations. I'm trying to get function_3 to call function_2 and calculate using the same formula. The array will be a multidimensional numpy array. I keep getting errors like this:

```
NameError: name 'D' is not defined
```

I know it's a bit confusing but this is the best I could explain. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You're never calling your functions...

Comment: Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: Also, where is `function_3` getting `C` from?

Comment: I just realised I had to change C to H. Now I'm getting a completely different error. ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: Do it step by step, not all at once. First, get the imports working (see answer given by Himanshu), then make sure your functions work on their own. Then start passing around variables.

Answer (score 1):

import like this in your function_3.py file

```
from function_1 import function_1 as f1
from function_2 import function_2 as f2
```

General function importing method:

```
from <file> import <func>
```

Here, the *first name* after *from* represents **filename** and *second one* represents **function name**